# NativeScript tns doctor command not found

Tags: npm, nativescript, npm-install

After NativeScript install like that: https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-os-x

When I ran the `tns doctor` command, only to find that command not found.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you try restarting the terminal?

Comment: yes, so many times

Comment: You could verify your path variable with `echo $PATH` in terminal, this should contain the path to your node bin.

Comment: is it possible you explain more?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can following the instructions [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/start/quick-setup). Please be sure,

install Node.js [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

execute `npm install -g nativescript`

If you have installed both Node.js and nativescript, and you are still unable to execute `tns doctor`, you might check if the installation path is part of your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

> Find where NativeScript installed to on your computer Point your
>   various bash profiles there. For your reference, 
>        I used this: `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/lib/node_modules/nativescript/bin`

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, but have you tried `source ~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: Sorry to hear @MuhammedHanifiAlma, also wondering, what OS are you working on?